# How to get SLOPE to work with excel array formula

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I cannot get an array formula to calculate a slope for a range that meet specific requirements.

I have tried multiplying logical arrays and using `IF` combined with multiplication of logical arrays and the `AND` function.
I am using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

```
{=SLOPE(B2:B50>C3*B2:B50<D3*B2:B50,B2:B50>C3*B2:B50<D3*A2:A50)}
```

The result I get doing a manual selection of the data with formula below is 0.060

```
=-SLOPE(B11:B22,A11:A22)
```

The data in columns A B C and D for the formulas above is shown below (Copied and pasted from Excel for range `A1:D50`)

```
X   Z   Lower limit Upper limit
0.0000  -2.7800     
-7.3772 -2.4100 -2.000  2.000
-17.7452    -2.4600     
-26.2190    -2.3900     
-26.9169    -2.3800     
-32.3999    -2.2600     
-39.9765    -2.4100     
-43.0670    -3.4200     
-46.3568    -2.1100     
-51.5408    -1.4600     
-59.8153    -0.3200     
-70.4823    0.3200      
-79.1556    1.1500      
-80.4516    1.7900      
-83.6417    1.8600      
-87.0312    1.9700      
-94.2091    1.5900      
-96.2029    1.6500      
-98.5955    1.8100      
-101.1875   1.9000      
-103.8792   1.9700      
-106.7703   2.0500      
-109.9604   2.1200      
-250.0000   3.4893      
-500.0000   4.0122      
-750.0000   4.5100      
-1000.0000  4.8634      
-1250.0000  5.3061      
-1288.8200  5.3600      
-1500.0000  5.6058      
-1750.0000  6.1516      
-2000.0000  6.7061      
-2250.0000  7.2345      
-2500.0000  7.6140      
-2750.0000  7.8903      
-3000.0000  8.3610      
-3250.0000  9.1905      
-3500.0000  9.7509      
-3750.0000  10.2806     
-4000.0000  10.7127     
-4250.0000  11.1371     
-4500.0000  11.8694     
-4750.0000  12.5736     
-5000.0000  13.1958     
-5250.0000  13.7533     
-5500.0000  14.3108     
-5750.0000  14.8683     
-6000.0000  15.4257     
-6250.0000  15.9808
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to make this work?

Comment: do you mean `=SLOPE(IF(B2:B50>C3, B2:B50, C3*B2:B50))`?

Comment: No. I Meant {=SLOPE((B2:B50>C3)*(B2:B50<D3)*(B2:B50),(B2:B50>C3)*(B2:B50<D3)*(A2:A50))}  or   {=SLOPE(IF((B2:B50>C3)*(B2:B50<D3),B2:B50),IF((B2:B50>C3)*(B2:B50<D3),A2:A50))}